# Adding two rasters in modeller

Tags: qgis, gdal, raster-calculator, saga

I'm trying to build a process model which uses a series of raster operations - Rasterize, Proximity, Raster Calculator. However, I couldn't seem to add two consecutive raster calculator processes.

[image]

From the model, I have two raster calculators branching out from a gdal_proximity, and what I want to do is to add these two rasters. I used saga for the raster calculator because this is the only one I've tried which can take a numerical user input in the modeller.

Answer (score 1):

see the picture below, just use "additional layers (optional)"

[image]

Comment: That is what I did with the 'sum_saga' step but the formula I used was a+b. Should I use the layer name instead?

Comment: I've tried using the three different raster calculators but none of them work for my model. I've tried investigating and I think the problem occurs when the input rasters are temporary layers.